# Value does not fall under expected range - caml query view fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

i am trying to update 2 hyperlink fields  (internal names=Hlink1,Hlink2) in powershell,but i am getting **"Value does not fall under expected range"** error once it hits **$Item.SystemUpdate()**, but if i remove the $spqQuery.ViewFields it will work fine with out any problem. 
(below is the code sample)

```
 $spList = $spWeb.Lists[$List.Title]
                $spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
                $spqQuery.Query= "<Query><Where> 
                                <Geq> 
                                    <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
                                    <Value Type='Counter'>1
                                         </Value> 
                                             </Geq> 
                                                </Where></Query>"                           
                $spqQuery.ViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Hlink1'/><FieldRef Name='Hlink2'/></ViewFields>"
                $spqQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
                if($spqQuery -ne $null)
                {
                $splListItems = $spList.GetItems($spqQuery) 
                } 

                Write-Host $splListItems.Count

            foreach($Item in $splListItems)
            {
                $UrlField= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue($Item["Hlink1"])
                $UrlField.Url=$UrlField.Url
                $UrlField.Description = $UrlField.Url.ToString()
                $Item[$Field.InternalName]= $UrlField.Description
                $Item["Title"]= "abcd"
                $Item.SystemUpdate()
            }
```

Comment: in above code i cannot see the $true variable you can try with replacing $true to true. at $spqQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field used in  $Item[$Field.InternalName] is included in ViewFields definition, if this field is not included in the ViewFields, it will throw Value not fall under expected range.